# NTFS file transfers on my Mac USB 3.0 thumbdrive are very slow

Tags: macos, usb

On my MacBook Pro running Mohave, I'm trying to copy 7 million small files to my USB 3 thumbdrive.  It says it's going to take about six months.  The total size of the files is just ~23Gb.

Even when I grab just a few hundred files it takes several minutes to copy then to the drive.

I have tried changing the privacy settings so that spotlight doesn't index the file, I've tried both exFat and NTFS, and they are all extraordinarily slow.  I'm not sure what to try next.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the meta-operations are killing you - creating files and inserting them into directories.

I would try using `tar` or `7-zip` to put all the files into a single archive and copying that to your NTFS-formatted thumb drive as a single file.

So, if you are in a directory with 7 million files called XYZ.dat, you can create a tarball with:

```
tar cv -T <(find . -name "*dat") -f tarball.tar
```

Then you just need to copy the single 23GB file called `tarball.tar` to your thumb drive.

If, as I presume, you are moving the thumb drive to Windows, you can use `7-zip` to extract the files.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need the files already unpacked on the drive.